# Android how to delete items from list with longclicklistener

Tags: android, list, listview, arraylist

I just started working with lists, so this might be a stupid question but I don't know how to do it, I have checked a lot of similar questions but their information is complex. My list in which I have only numbers is going to be only between 1 and 10 items long enter by the user from a EditText box, so is simple, at display I want to make the user be able to delete items from this list by long pressing the item row, how do I accomplish this?

This is my code:

```
final ArrayList<Double> individuallist = new ArrayList<Double>();
final ArrayAdapter<Double> bb;
bb = new ArrayAdapter<Double>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ,individuallist);
listView.setAdapter(bb);

   // add button
    
    Button addbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnnext);
    addbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                           iamount = amountText.getText().toString();
                       it = Double.valueOf(iamount);
            individuallist.add(0, it);
            bb.notifyDataSetChanged();
            item1.setText("");
        }
    });
```

This is how I declare my list and add items to it: item1 is a EditText box where I get the user amount. How can I delete individual items in my list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the item to be deleted from the list when the user long clicks on the item in the list, call [setOnItemLongClickListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemLongClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener%29) on your listview.

From your implementation of `OnItemLongClickListener`, you will get the position. You can then update your `ListAdapter`. It might looking something like,

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemLongClick((AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    MyAdapter adapter = (MyAdapter)listView.getAdapter();
    myAdapter.removeItemAt(pos); // you need to implement this method
    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
));
```

Comment: How would you go about implementing the `myAdapter.removeItemAt(pos);` method? I can only choose `myAdapter.remove(object)`.

Comment: Best way is to remove the value from the ArrayList bb.remove(pos) and call notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: in your adapter, you typically have a list of the objects that back the list. just implement a method to call through to the list and remove the item at the particular position.

Comment: That would only work if you make your own adapter though right? Or how would I add a new method to Android's own ArrayAdapter<T>?

Comment: the bottom line is: to remove an item from a list view, remove the item from the list adapter backing the list view. how you go about that depends on your source. since i don't have all your source in front of my it's hard to answer that. ultimately you constructed the array adapter, so you can holder a reference to the list, or array data you used to construct it. how you go about modifying that depends on how you have constructed your application.

Comment: Great Thanks it work, I use 
          individuallist.remove(position);
           bb.notifyDataSetChanged();